# Are ternary operations carried out at compile-time?

Tags: c, performance, ternary-operator

I am making a bitboard-based chess engine from scratch in C. The move generation procedure is particularly time-sensitive. Currently, my code is like this:

```
void generate_moves(Position *p, Colour side, Move *list) {
    if(side == WHITE) {
        Bitboard b1 = p->piece_bitboards[BLACK_KNIGHT];
        Bitboard top_rank_mask = MASK_RANK[RANK8];
        ...
    } else {
        Bitboard b1 = p->piece_bitboards[WHITE_KNIGHT];
        Bitboard top_rank_mask = MASK_RANK[RANK1];
        ...
    }
}
```

and several other hundred lines of code which are either mirrored for black and white, or the same. However, this seems bug-prone and obfuscated to me.

So will replacing the large if-else with a ternary operator at each fork to increase readability:

```
void generate_moves(Position *p, Colour side, Move *list) {
    Bitboard b1 = p->piece_bitboards[side == WHITE ? WHITE_KNIGHT : 
        BLACK_KNIGHT];
    Bitboard top_rank_mask = MASK_RANK[side == WHITE ? RANK8 : RANK1];
    ...
}
```

have similar performance? All ternary operators depend on the variable side, which can assume the constant values WHITE or BLACK only.

Comment: They can't possibly be done at compile-time, since they depend on run-time variables.

Comment: You've replaced a single branch with hundred of branches. Naturally, it should come at a (performance) cost. And as a side note, I would say that there doesn't seem to be any good reason to give this question a downvote. It is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any compiler of moderate quality will treat the two code sequences the same, unless optimization is disabled.

The second sequence nominally has two or more tests, but a compiler should recognize the duplicated expression and the fact that it cannot change from one statement to the next, because the operands in it are not affected by anything in the prior statement(s) (`Bitboard b1 = p->piece_bitboards[side == WHITE ? WHITE_KNIGHT : 
BLACK_KNIGHT];`). (Presumably `WHITE` is a constant.) Such optimizations are expected of compilers of even moderate quality.

As to whether the selection (of one of the two blocks in the `if` sequence or of the ternary operands in the other case) will be made at compile time, this cannot happen unless the compiler knows the value of `side`. Since `side` is a function parameter, the compiler cannot know its value from the source code of the function alone. It could know its value if the compiler can see where the function is called and the argument passed for `side` is a constant expression or can be otherwise deduced by the compiler. For example, if the calling code contains two sequences, one of which calls `generate_moves` for `WHITE` and the other of which calls `generate_moves` for `BLACK`, it is possible the compiler would generate inline code for `generate_moves` in which the selection had been optimized out in each case.

The circumstances under which this would be done are less clear and more subject to properties of the compiler and the other code, which you have not shown.

Performance in code like this is likely to be much more affected by other factors than the condition selection you have identified.